# how can we display the elements of an integer type array in C#

Tags: c#

i M declaring an int type array and trying to print all its elements but it prints only last element .....give me the right code.....

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] arr;
        int range;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            range = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            arr = new int[range];


        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i =0;i<range;i++)
            {
                textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + arr[i].ToString();

            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line: `arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);`  will set every element in the array to the value in textbox2.  Is that your intent?

Answer (score 0):

Int arrays are common. They store many integer values. And these values can be used in many ways. This introductory material covers int arrays, showing declarations, assignments, elements, loops and methods.please see [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-array)

this code is simple example that work array int

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    int[] arr1 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 }; // Declare int array
    int[] arr2 = { 3, 4, 5 };           // Another
    var arr3 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };   // Another

    int[] arr4 = new int[3];            // Declare int array of zeros
    arr4[0] = 3;
    arr4[1] = 4;
    arr4[2] = 5;

    if (arr1[0] == arr2[0] &&
        arr1[0] == arr3[0] &&
        arr1[0] == arr4[0])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First elements are the same");
    }
    }
}

using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Loop over array of integers.
    foreach (int id in GetEmployeeIds())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
    // Loop over array of integers.
    int[] employees = GetEmployeeIds();
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(employees[i]);
    }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an array of integers.
    /// </summary>
    static int[] GetEmployeeIds()
    {
    int[] employees = new int[5];
    employees[0] = 1;
    employees[1] = 3;
    employees[2] = 5;
    employees[3] = 7;
    employees[4] = 8;
    return employees;
    }
}

Output

1
3
5
7
8
1
3
5
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Is textBox2.Text one number, or a sequence of numbers? If it is, for example, 1,2,3 then you'll have to `Split` the string on `,` and then convert each entry of the `String[]` you get back to an integer, and store those in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do.

It appears that you are reading an input from a textbox whenever it is changed
and recreating the array to the size indicated in that textbox.

The second textbox fills the array whenever it is changed to whatever the second
textbox accepts as input (this makes no sense at all).

button1 displays array as a string, which is probably alright.

You might want to change the 2nd textbox into a button which fills the array.

Otherwise, rethink your intent of 2nd textbox, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you clear textBox3.Text ?

You are accumulating in this text box. When you do that, and the input overflows, you will only see the last thing added. Perhaps this is the problem. I might tweak:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = "";

    for(int i =0;i<range;i++)
    {
        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + arr[i].ToString();

    }
}
```